# How to implement multiplication-merge of two std::map<unsigned, unsigned>?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdmap

imagine two maps like this:

```
const std::map<unsigned, unsigned> s0{{0, 1}, {2, 2}};
const std::map<unsigned, unsigned> s1{{0, 2}, {1, 3}};
```

And what I would like to get is

```
{{0, 3/*1+2*/}, {1, 3/*0+3*/}, {2, 2/*2+0*/}};
```

Means the mapped value in the destination should be the sum of the mapped values in the source.
The key values are indices.

BTW -- this applies to multiplying two coefficients of a polynomials with each other -- the power accumulates. E.g. imagine two polynomials with multiple independent variables x0..x2. One might have a coefficient for x0 * x1^2 * x2^3. The map for this coefficient would be {{0,1},{1,2},{2,3}}. Multiply this with x0^3 and one would get x0^4 * x1^2 * x2^3.

```
for (auto p0 = s0.begin(), p1 = s1.begin();
    p0 != s0.end() || p1 != s1.end();)
    if (p0 != s0.end())
        if (p1 != s1.end())
            if (p0->first < p1->first)
                s.insert(*p0++);
            else
            if (p0->first > p1->first)
                s.insert(*p1++);
            else
            {    s.insert(std::make_pair(p0->first, p0->second + p1->second));
                 ++p0;
                 ++p1;
             }
        else
        {    s.insert(p0, s0.end());
             p0 = s0.end();
        }
     else
     {    s.insert(p1, s1.end());
          p1 = s1.end();
     }
```

I know how to implement this using a for-loop (see above). But I wonder if it can be done using something like std::merge(). I thought that one one would need an overloaded std::inserter() in order accumulate the mapped value. Is there any more elegant way?

Comment: i dont understand how the result is connected to the two input maps. Why are there three elements in the output?

Comment: I don't think there is anything standard, I looked when I needed a variant of set_intersection that lets me compute a new value from 2 "equal" values (your case would be a variant of set_union), but I had to write a loop in the end.

Comment: (you can pass a hint to the insert function since you are building it in order)

Comment: After compiling, there are no loops anywhere. Just jumps and branches and tests. Consoling fact! ;) So we talk about aesthetics here. Solution: 1) Damn aesthetics 2) use goto 3) hide the loop or use recursion in a (higher) function. I propose something like `template <class K, class V, class COAL> std::map<K,V> coalesce(COAL coalescer, std::pair<K,V> *first, std::pair<K,V> *last)` (or something like that). And before you call this work of wonder, you put all the key-value pairs into a list or a vector and sort it so entries with the same key are adjacent to each other.

Comment: This seems to be more of an add-merge rather than a multiply-merge.  It can be used to add two polynomials in this map form.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the 2nd map and add the values of it's keys to the value of the same key in 1st map.

```
for (const auto& p: s1)
    s0[p.first] += p.second;
```

If it's not possible to modify the first map, make a copy in a third map and add into that.

Comment: Only half the solution. There could be keys in s0 which are not contained in s1 and thus your result would be missing some stuff.

Comment: @BitTickler the answer suggests to add to `s0` so the result cannot miss elements present in `s0`, though `s0` is `const`

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a standard algorithm that does what you want out-of-the box. `std::merge` is to sort two sorted ranges, so it does not help here. Though, the loop can be simpler:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    const std::map<unsigned, unsigned> s0{{0, 1}, {2, 2}};
    const std::map<unsigned, unsigned> s1{{0, 2}, {1, 3}};

    std::map<unsigned,unsigned> result = s0;
    for (const auto& e : s1) result[e.first] += e.second;
    
    for (const auto& e : result){
        std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << "\n";
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/3zYv7aP5q):

```
0 3
1 3
2 2
```

PS: Maybe I misunderstand, but I don't see how this multiplies polynomials. If one polynomial is `2x^2 + 1` and the other is `3x + 2` then their product is `6x^3 + 4x^2 + 3x + 2` which you obtain via:

```
std::map<unsigned,unsigned> result;
for (const auto& e0 : s0) {
    for (const auto& e1 : s1){
        result[e0.first + e1.first] += e0.second * e1.second;
    }
}
```